# angular animation stagger with random delay

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

I am trying to display multiple divs inside an `*ngFor` loop using a `stagger` blink animation. To achieve a kind of glitching effect, I'd want the stagger animation delay between each loop to be a random number between `0.5s` to `1s`.

```js
 trigger('stagger', [
      transition('* => *', [ 
        query(':enter', [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            stagger((Math.random() * (1000 - 500) + 1000), [animate('0.1s', style({ opacity: 1}))])
          ], { optional: true }
        )
      ])
    ]),
```

That doesn't work. It sets the same random delay on all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that is impossible with angular animation. in any way you use animations you pass staggertime for the whole group.

If it is acceptable for you, I would try to implement it with several renders, by adding new element after a random delay

```
this.data$ = from(data).pipe(
  concatMap((item) => timer(Math.random() * (1000 - 500) + 1000).pipe(map(() => item))),
  scan((a,b) => a.concat(b), [])
);
```

and then render it

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data$ | async">
...yourtemplate
```